# How to cover logic for enforcing FLS in test class for lightning controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, salesforce-id, aura

How to test code for enforcing FLS.
I have a test class that only has 75% coverage. I need to test for when the user does not have Read access to Client_Strategy__c  custom field in FLS and I also need to Cover 'Catch'.
[image]

```
@isTest
```

public class CI_ClientOverviewControllerTest {

```
@testSetup
static void setupTestData() {   
    List<Account> client = new List<Account>();        
    client.add(new Account(Name= 'Google Inc',Client_Strategy__c = 'Strategy for the client'));
    insert client;  
}
public static testMethod void PositiveTest(){
    setupTestData(); 
    List<Account> client = [select id from Account where name ='Google Inc'];    
    CI_ClientOverviewController.getBankStrategy(client[0].id);
}
```

}

Comment: @Eric How?, do you perhaps have an example I can look at?

Comment: Nevermind runAs does not respect FLS. See this answer - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34859/apex-unit-test-doesnt-obey-crud-security